# Forcing broswers to use a different host and port when viewing websites over ssh-tunnels

Tags: ssh-tunneling, port-forwarding, http

I've setup an ssh tunnel to a network that has a website I need to view.

However, when requesting the page my browsers sends the host `localhost` and url `http://localhost:1234` in the HTTP headers. Is there a way to spoof this information, if there's a browser specific way of doing it that works for chromium or firefox, that will be useable.

SSH Setup:

```
Host mytunnel
    User myname
    HostName host.example.com 
    ExitOnForwardFailure true
    LocalForward 1234 host.example.com:80
```

The only way I can think of now is setting up a virtual machine that runs a DNS server and sets up the tunnels on the right ports.

Comment: Put the sites host name in `/etc/hosts` with IP address `127.0.0.1`, and use the site host name in the URL. (Keep the tunnel port number part).

Comment: Please [edit] and clarify your question. How is the tunnel set up? Does port `1234` point to the tunnel? What information do you want to spoof? Do you want to use a different URL transparently and have that point to `localhost:1234`?

Comment: @terdon edited;

Comment: @Mattbianca your solution worked, though I wish there was a way of only easily enabling and disabling it (I sometimes take this laptop to work) and could do it without root privileges (but this is good enough)